# Can I create surveys with unique URLs for each recipient?

Tags: 7

Does anybody know if there's a module that can support unique URLs for survey participants?

To clarify, what I mean is, I'd like to send out letters/ documentation to people in a particular geographic area. I'd like to encourage them to complete a survey, but for each recipient of the letter I'd like to assign a unique URL for their survey, which can then be used by me to marry them up to the data I already hold about them.

So, for example:

Person A receives a letter and is given a survey URL of www.mysite.com/ab123
Person B receives a letter and is given a survey URL of www.mysite.com/eg462
Person C receives a letter and is given a survey URL of www.mysite.com/qt368

and so on.

For a number of reasons, this method is better for my data collection purposes, rather than asking participants to include an assigned ID number or their own details.

Comment: What will you be using to create the survey? Webform? Node creation? A custom module? Something else?

Comment: Well, I'm open-minded at the moment. I have no set preference about how it's achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the webform API](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--webform--webform_hooks.php/7/source) in a [tiny module](http://drupal.org/node/416986) to access the form to add a [hidden element](http://loganjameslynn.com/2010/08/17/creating-hidden-fields-using-drupal-form-api/) to it. Then use the handy [Drupal arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function to determine the value of your unique URL argument. After, use the webform API function to change values before saving to the hidden field for administration usage later.

I can't guarantee this will work so hopefully some of the other Drupal Stack Exchange folks can verify this.

Comment: Thanks, Adam.

Hopefully some others can shed some light on how they might do it?